# Gnuplot: What is the difference between plot '/dev/stdin' and plot '-'?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, gnuplot

When I use `'-'` to plot in gnuplot from a pipeline, as follows<sup>⭐</sup>:

```
$ seq 5 | gnuplot -e "plot '-' w lp; pause 99"
```

it works fine, I can adjust the plot's window size, can show/hide grid without any problem.

But when I use `'/dev/stdin'` as follows:

```
$ seq 5 | gnuplot -e "plot '/dev/stdin' w lp; pause 99"
```

It shows the plot but when I click to maximize the window, it crashes:

```
line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

plot '/dev/stdin' w lp
                      ^
line 0: x range is invalid
```

Could you please explain why does this happen? what is the difference between `'-'` and `'/dev/stdin'`?

---

<sub>⭐ I am deliberately using `pause` instead of using `-p` option, because the latter doesn't allow interaction with the plot (no update after resize, can't show/hide grid from the toolbar,etc.)</sub>
<sub>️ I am using bash version 5.0.17 on Ubuntu 20.04, gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 8, if that info is needed.</sub>

Comment: You will notice that the Gnuplot manual has quite a lot to say about the special file `'-'`, but that it doesn't mention `/dev/stdin` a single time.

Comment: This looks like some kind of bug. Curiously, using a *named* pipe (fifo), (or `/dev/stdin` with gnuplot's stdin redirected from one) seems to work fine. Stracing it shows that gnuplot tries to open `/dev/stdin` multiple times when called with `... | gnuplot ... plot '/dev/stdin'`, so it appears that it misidentifies the pipe as a regular file.

Comment: @they care to elaborate?

Comment: I'm assuming it has special semantics for `-` and probably saves it to a temporary file or internal buffer where it can re-read it. The `/dev/stdin` file is not seekable, so it will fail if it tries to re-read data from it. To me, it seems the most reasonable explanation, but I'm just hand-waving as I only have the manual and haven't looked at the source code.

Comment: @they it's totally correct that it does handle `-` specially (which is bad enough ;-)). But that doesn't explain why it doesn't fail in the same way with other non-seekable files, but only with anonymous pipes.

Comment: @UncleBilly: https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2463/

Comment: @they https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2463/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'-'` is recognized as a special case, as part of which the `refresh` command is substituted for `replot` wherever possible. This means that the program reuses data previously read rather than trying to reread data from the previous source.  Also note that `'-'` means "the current input stream", which is not necessarily stdin.

`'/dev/stdin'` on the other hand just looks like a normal filename to gnuplot, so a "replot" command tries to read from it again. That would work only if you fed the in the same data a second time. In an interactive session the program prompts you to do so.

As to why you and someone else see different behavior for the `-persist` mode, I'd have to know a lot more about what you both tried.  Note that different terminals implement the persist mode differently. From the documentation:

```
Depending on the terminal type, some mousing operations may still be possible
in the persistent window.  However operations like zoom/unzoom  that require
redrawing the plot are not possible because the main program has exited.
If you want to leave a plot window open and fully mouseable after creating
the plot, for example when running gnuplot from a script file rather than
interactively, see `pause mouse close`.
```